# Can I run a pg_dump automatically removing reference to the owner?

Tags: bash, postgresql, pg-dump, database-cloning

I want to be able to clone the contents of our postgre production database to an ownerless local database efficiently. I've successfully done this, but it was a laborious process with the following steps

```
$ pg_dump [prod_db] > tempfile

[Go through tempfile manually removing all 60ish references to the owner, named 'postgres']

$ cat tempfile > psql [local_db]
```

Otherwise when I ran the last step, I got a bunch of SQL error messages saying `ERROR:  role "postgres" does not exist`. I tried recreating the local db with a matching 'postgres' owner, but a) I still got the same type of errors, and b) I don't want to have an owner set for my local database if it means I'll have to log into it.

Is there a best practice/efficient way of doing this if I want to re-clone it in future?

Answer (score 2):

Use the -O switch to not have an owner defined in the dump.

Answer (score 0):

Not having an owner set is not normal Postgres design. To avoid having to login to your postgres database you can setup a .pgpass file. This is a plain text file and should be set with 600 permissions. The contents will look like:

```
hostname:port:database:username:password
```

Each connection can be on one line.

Additionally, for local db connections, assuming you have setup the rest of your security properly (ssh certs, etc) you can edit your pg_hba.conf file and set local connection authentication method to "trust." This is obviously not recommended for production or sensitive data. The line would look like this:

```
local   all             all                                     trust
```

The default method is "peer". Unless you set your username in a .pgpass file you will still need to connect with `psql -U postgres` but you will not need to enter a password.